# How to get the SIFT features of an image?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, image

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageKeypoints.html), the function `KeyPoints[]` computes features only using SURF, but what about SIFT or FAST features?

Comment: SIFT is patented. FAST is rather special-purpose, focusing only on corner detection. Those are IMO the most probable reasons why these algorithms have not been implemented.

Comment: @OleksandrR as the user mentions SURF is patented too...